# Detect incorrect points in a homogeneous surface

Tags: matlab, math, error-detection

In my project i have hige surfaces of 20.000 points computed by a algorithm. This algorithm, sometimes, has an error, computing 1 or more points in an small area incorrectly.

This error can not be solved in the algorithm, but needs to be detected afterwards.

The error can be seen in the next figure:

[image]

As you can see, there is a point wrongly computed that not only breaks the full homogeneous surface, but also  destroys the aestetics of the plot (wich is also important in the project.)

Sometimes it can be more than a point, in general no more than 5 or 6. The error is allways the Z axis, so no need to check X and Y

I have been squeezing my mind to find a bit "generic" algorithm to detect this poitns.
I thougth that maybe taking patches of surface and meaning the Z, then detecting the points out of the variance... but I dont think it will work allways.

Any ideas?

**NOTE**: I dont want someone to write code for me, just an idea.

PD: relevant code for the avobe image:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid([-2:.07:2]);
Z = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2);
subplot(1,2,1)
surf(x,y,Z,gradient(Z))
subplot(1,2,2)
Z(35,35)=Z(35,35)+0.3;
surf(x,y,Z,gradient(Z))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your functions seems to vary smoothly these abrupt changes can be detected by looking into the derivatives. You can

1. Take the derivative in one direction
2. Calculate mean and standard deviation of derivative
3. Find the points by looking for points that are further from mean by certain multiple of standard deviation.

Here is the code

```
U=diff(Z);
V=(U-mean(U(:)))/std(U(:));
surf(x(2:end,:),y(2:end,:),V)
V=[zeros(1,size(V,2)); V];
V(abs(V)<10)=0;
V=sign(V);
W=cumsum(V);
[I,J]=find(W);
outliers = [I, J];
```

For your example you get this plot for `V` with a peak at around 21.7 while second peak is at around 1.9528, so maybe a threshold of 10 is ok.
[image]

and running the code returns

```
outliers =

    35    35
```

The need for `cumsum` is for the cases that you have a patch of points next to each other that are incorrect.

Comment: this seems pretty nice. ill try it and let you know the resut

Comment: Good answer but the `cumsum` does not work for two consecutive outliers on the same column. Also `10` is rather arbitrary. At least `3` is a standard number corresponding to p-value ~ 0.001. Although if it's a manual process for the OP, he can always change this number to find more or fewer outliers.

Comment: It works fine for two consecutive outliers on the same column. Change `Z(35,35)=Z(35,35)+0.3;` to `Z(35:36,35)=Z(35:36,35)+0.3;` and test it.

Comment: Actually the cumsum does not work very well. I tried a similar surface but with real data. Before the Cumsum there is only 1 outlier, but if you add the cumsum line 57 appear. Thery are the whole line where the outluier is.

Comment: @Bee Yeah, there will be a GUI, so a threeshold for the weth can be manually set

Comment: Can you share the vactor of values in that column?

Comment: Buf... Ill check. However the thing is that before the Cumsum, the onli point in V matrix is the only outlier. But when cumsum is used the full row has the value, as it accumulates the value of V during the matrix. So from the outlier to the end, all the points became outliers, when they were not. The reason is that the positive peak is of hidher value than the negative peak, and the negative is not detected.

Comment: That's weird, probably the threshold is too close the peak value. If you reduce it so that it can capture the falling edge, it should be fine. The idea is that since the surface is smooth, there should not be that much change between positive and negative peaks, otherwise it means that there has been a huge change in the functions value while passing just one point.

Answer (score 3):

The standard trick is to use a Laplacian, looking for the largest outliers. (This is not unlike what Mohsen posed for an answer, but is actually a bit easier.) You could even probably do it with conv2, so it would be pretty efficient.

I could offer a few ways to implement the idea. A simple one is to use my gridfit tool, found on the File Exchange. (Gridfit essentially uses a Laplacian for its smoothing operation.) Fit the surface with all points included, then look for the single point that was perturbed the most by the fit. Exclude it, then rerun the fit, again looking for the largest outlier. (With gridfit, you can use weights to give points a zero weight, a simple way to exclude a point or list of points.) When the largest perturbation that was needed is small enough, you can decide to stop the process. A nice thing is gridfit will also impute new values for the outliers, filling in all of the holes.

A second approach is to use the Laplacian directly, in more of a filtering approach. Here, you simply compute a value at each point that is the average of each neighbor to the left, right, above, and below. The single value that is most largely in disagreement with its computed average is replaced with a new value. Or, you can use a weighted average of the new value with the old one there. Again, iterate until the process does not generate anything larger than some tolerance. (This is the basis of an old outlier detection and correction scheme that I recall from the Fortran IMSL libraries, but probably dates back to roughly 30 years ago.)

Comment: So your Laplacian proposition is to use del2(Z) instead of deff(Z), right? That seems more logical

Comment: +1: Laplacian seems a way better and more robust approach. You learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: Yes. A "smooth" surface should have del^2 small everywhere.

Comment: Your answer is more full of info but his answer is more elaborated. I didnt know which one to accpet so I decided his because he is the lowes point one. I whis I could accept your answers both!